# Spreadsheets on Shared Drive Sometimes Revert Cells Back to Old Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive

Currently experiencing an issue with our shared drive giving us old/deleted values back into our spreadsheets.

Example: One user has removed an email address from a spreadsheet but that same email address has reappeared the day after.

We access our shared drive via OneDrive so no on-site shared drive.

Not sure where to start with troubleshooting. All user accounts seem to be working fine on OneDrive and the spreadsheets are being synced. I'm thinking maybe it's a OneDrive issue but not sure where to start with that.

Anyone experienced similar issues?

Thanks.

Comment: Does more than one person edit the file at the same time? How does OneDrive handle this?

Comment: the irony of sharepoint and one drive is, that they are not very good for sharing

Comment: I'm not sure how OneDrive handles multiple users editing the same file. Occassionally if this is the case it may ask them to save a copy of the file but these files should really only be being edited by one user at a time.

Comment: I can only agree with the fact that sharepoint and onedrive are not very good for sharing, lol

Comment: Did you sync any folders?

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally done this, but from a pure file management point of view can see how this happens if two users have the same workbook open, makes changes and save. Most basic file systems do not handle conflicting changes out of the box (other than overwrite, skip or rename). At best something like dropbox or onedrive will keep a file history or backup (although both of these do support co-authoring in some way... read on).

To handle concurrent updates, the software editing the file must handle or be aware of the multi-user access. Something like google sheets does this out of the box. In Excel you must specifically enable the sharing features. See this article https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/08/02/excel-shared-workbook-share-file-multiple-users/.

The first part of the article deals with old school sharing via a network drive. Near the end it addresses sharing via onedrive. I guess (and hope) that you must specifically share the file from within Excel. Simply copying the file to onedrive doesn't enable the internal multi-user "track changes" required.

Comment: Let me guess further... if you simply copy a file into a shared onedrive folder, the file could be sync'ed to other people hard drives via the desktop client for offline access. If you share it from within excel, the default will be for others to edit the file via Excel online by clicking the share link. They will not be able to "sync" or "always keep on this device" from the desktop client. They could click "edit in excel" from Excel Online, which would ensure the cloud copy is being edited live.